# Makefile - generating thumbnails from pictures

Tags: unix, makefile, gnu

I'm trying to make a Makefile. I have one folder called pictures and one called thumbs. In pictures there are pictures called pic1.jpg, pic2.jpg, pic3.jpg, and so on. I want to make thumbnails from these pictures and place them in the thumbs folder. This is what I have tried:

```
infiles = $(wildcard pictures/*.jpg) 
outfiles = $(subst pictures,thumbs, $(infiles))
all : $(outfiles)
       convert -thumbnail 100 pictures/*.jpg thumbs/*.jpg
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How is it not working? Does the destination directory exist? Does it already contain some or all of these files?

Answer (score 2):

Your makefile says "here is how to crate `all`; it can be made when all the `outfiles` are up to date", but you don't say how to create those files.

A more idiomatic apprach is to specify a dependency for each individual file, and then Make can take it from there. In other words, say that `all` depends on `outfiles` just like you did, but then separately specify how each `outfile` depends on its respective `infile`.

```
infiles = $(wildcard pictures/*.jpg) 
outfiles = $(subst pictures,thumbs, $(infiles))

.PHONY: all
all : $(outfiles)

thumbs/%.jpg: pictures/%.jpg
    mkdir -p thumbs
    # Guesswork here; probably update the command
    convert -thumbnail 100 $< $@
```

The `.PHONY` declaration marks `all` as just a target name, not a file which needs to be built only if it doesn't exist, or is older than its dependencies.